How to Dynamically Set Tooltip Background Colors in amCharts 5 PieChart?
I'm trying to set up a PieChart using amCharts 5, and I want to dynamically pass a color parameter to the tooltip so that each tooltip displays a different background color for each slice of the chart (as shown in the diagram). I have tried multiple approaches and events, but nothing seems to be working for me.
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/percent.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<script>
    // Create root and chart
    var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
    var chart = root.container.children.push(
        am5percent.PieChart.new(root, {
            layout: root.verticalHorizontal
        })
    );

    // Define data
    var data = [{
        country: "France",
        sales: 100000,
        color: am5.color(0x87CEEB)
    }, {
        country: "Spain",
        sales: 160000,
        color: am5.color(0x228B22)
    }, {
        country: "United Kingdom",
        sales: 80000,
        color: am5.color(0xFF7F50)
    }];

    // Create series
    var series = chart.series.push(
        am5percent.PieSeries.new(root, {
            name: "Series",
            valueField: "sales",
            categoryField: "country"
        })
    );

    series.data.setAll(data);

    let tooltip = am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
        getFillFromSprite: false
    });

    tooltip.get("background").setAll({
        fill: am5.color(0xeeeeee)
    });

    series.set("tooltip", tooltip);

</script>


